# How to flag if BigQuery scheduled refresh failed to run in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, flags

I have dozens of BQ connections in google sheets and one thing I've always wanted to build was a tab that showed me whether all the refreshes ran correctly, and flag any that didn't. I realize this is already solved by just going to the BigQuery tab and then selecting refresh options and seeing which ones ran and which didn't, but I would prefer it to be the first thing I see. Eventually I would want to have a primary google sheet that shows me this same information across all of my reports, but I just want to start off with one report.

Any ideas of how this can be done?

Thanks!

I've been searching to see if I can find anything but nothing has come up.